# External access on Apache2

Tags: networking, apache2, ssl

I want to enable external access on Apache 2.
This is the scheme I have:

> Domain -> Subdomain -> Mikrotik -> Apache2.

I used NAT on Mikrotik. On both, Mikrotik and Apache, I used the port 9191.
And, I enabled SSL.

Here are the configurations:

`ports.conf`:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 9191
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 9191
</IfModule>
```

`default-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:9191>
    ServerName srvweb2.queijoslelo.dc
    ServerAdmin webmster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
     HostNameLookups off
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled the SSL module with `sudo a2enmod ssl` and restarted apache?